# Looping through multiple webpages scraping the same information: Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using Python and Beautiful Soup to scrape through a webpage containing many settlements in Africa and Asia, each with their own webpage. This is the website: http://knowyourcity.info/explore-our-data/

I have this code to obtain attributes from an individual page:

```
from requests import get
url = 'http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1846/5119249'
response = get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
type(html_soup)

headers_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'settlement-base-status section text-center')
name = headers_containers.h2.text
year_established = headers_containers.h3.text

headers1_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'col-xs-12 text-center')
country = headers1_containers.h4.a.text

headers2_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'bold-it', id = "population")
population = headers2_containers.text
```

But I want to be able to loop through each settlement and put the attributes into a table, where the number at the end of the URL changes. However the numbers of the settlements do not change incrementally and seem fairly random to me. Does anyone know a loop function I could use for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data about settlements is loaded from external URL. You can use this script to construct the URLs:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://knowyourcity.info/wp-content/themes/sdinet/ajax/get-filter.php'

# sometimes the server returns error, so repeat 'till success:
while True:
    try:
        data = requests.post(url).json()
        break
    except:
        pass

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

u = 'http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/{}/{}'

for k, v in data['verified'].items():
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        if isinstance(vv, list):
            for vvv in vv:
                print('{:<20} {:<30} {:<50} {}'.format(k, kk, vvv['name'], u.format(vvv['form_id'], vvv['ona_id'])))
        else:
            for kkk, vvv in vv.items():
                print('{:<20} {:<30} {:<50} {}'.format(k, kk, vvv.get('name', '-'), u.format(vvv['form_id'], vvv['ona_id'])))
```

Prints:

```
38_benin             38001_cotonou        AGONKAME - TOTO                http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/344923/51863092
38_benin             38001_cotonou        Ahouansori Ague                http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/344923/43698638
38_benin             38001_cotonou        DJIDJE 1 AYINADJE              http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/344923/51327770
38_benin             38001_cotonou        hinde nord                     http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/344923/51869427
38_benin             38001_cotonou        KPANKPAN LA LIBERTE            http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/344923/51276811
38_benin             38001_cotonou        KPAYOCODJI                     http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/344923/51986803
38_benin             38001_cotonou        MIGBEHOUE                      http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/344923/51990855
38_benin             38001_cotonou        MINONTCHOU-TOTO                http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/344923/53173309
Ghana                Accra                ABELENKPE                      http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1846/5119249
Ghana                Accra                ABOFO                          http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1846/5193260
Ghana                Accra                ABOSSEY OKAI                   http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1846/9015532
Ghana                Accra                ACHIMOTA                       http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1846/5185027
Ghana                Accra                ADABRAKA                       http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1846/15080768

...and so on.
```

---

EDIT: To store URLs into a list, you can use:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://knowyourcity.info/wp-content/themes/sdinet/ajax/get-filter.php'

# sometimes the server returns error, so repeat 'till success:
while True:
    try:
        data = requests.post(url).json()
        break
    except:
        pass

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

u = 'http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/{}/{}'

urllist = []
for k, v in data['verified'].items():
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        if isinstance(vv, list):
            for vvv in vv:
                urllist.append(u.format(vvv['form_id'], vvv['ona_id']))
                print('{:<20} {:<30} {:<50} {}'.format(k, kk, vvv['name'], u.format(vvv['form_id'], vvv['ona_id'])))
        else:
            for kkk, vvv in vv.items():
                urllist.append(u.format(vvv['form_id'], vvv['ona_id']))
                print('{:<20} {:<30} {:<50} {}'.format(k, kk, vvv.get('name', '-'), u.format(vvv['form_id'], vvv['ona_id'])))

# all urls are inside urllist, print them on screen:
for u in urllist:
    print(u)
```

Prints:

```
...

http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1853/55602115
http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1853/10800809
http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1853/10801751
http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1853/10801676
http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1853/10800885
http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1853/10802010
http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1853/10800886
http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1853/10800915
http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1853/10801006
http://knowyourcity.info/settlement/1853/10801083
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this - really helpful. For the last section though I am returning an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-386-91aee68020d8>", line 3, in <module>
    if isinstance(vv, list):

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Comment: @Georgia you probably used before variable named `list` and shadowed built-in python type `list`. Rename your variable to something else.

Comment: Ah great yes that worked, sorry one more question as am quite new to this! How would I then loop through each of these URLs and extract information, does the above provide the URLs as a list? Thank you!

Comment: @Georgia See my edit. All URLs are inside `urllist`